# How to reenable PreventDefault without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm using a form with 4 different buttons.

Step 1: Enter a couple form fields

Step 2: Hit the run code button

Step 3: Ajax processes value for third form field

Step 4: Click "Save" Button and submit form.

The problem is when I hit the "Run Code" button, it works great. But because `preventDefault` is on, hitting the second button (Save) just repopulates the value for the third form field with a bunch of HTML code.

Instead, I want it to submit.

Here's my code.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $("#run-code").click(function()
    {
        $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
        {

            $("#SimpleLoader").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>");
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    $("#EmailAddress").val(data);
                    $("#run-code").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $("#save").removeAttr('disabled');

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    $("#EmailAddress").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind(e);

        });
            $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });
});
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="inc/scripts/email_api.php" method="POST"  novalidate>

<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" required />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" required/>       
</td>
<td>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" id="EmailAddress" placeholder="Email Address">
</td>
<td>
    <button id="run-code" name="getEmail" onclick="return validateForm()" >Run Code</button>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="save" onclick='this.form.action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"' id="save" disabled />
</td>
</form>
```

Comment: why not submitting the form only in the success callback `$(this).submit();` and then you'll no longer be in need to prevent any default !!

Comment: Because I don't want it to change pages when loading the results from the first submit button. I found a horrible workaround, so still looking for a solution. If not, I can post my workaround here.